# calling function from another function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions on a webpage, function A should be loaded at page generation (init), then after every 60 seconds OR when "Button1" is clicked and the Ajax Post is successful.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function A() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "html",
            data: {var1: "123"}
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(A, 60000);
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $('#Button1').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "html",
                data: {var2: "123"},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log( "Function Successful!" );
                    A();                   //CALL FUNCTION A - NOT WORKING
                },
            }); //End of AJAX
        });
    });
</script>
```

Function A alone works perfectly.

When I click on Button1 I got in the console a "Function Successful" message, BUT Function A is not being triggered.

How can I run function A when Button1 is clicked and Ajax is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function in same scope. Currently you have defined your function `A` in another scope.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function A() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "html",
            data: {var1: "123"},
            // remove this},
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(A, 60000);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#Button1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "html",
            data: {var2: "123"},
            success: function(data){
                console.log( "Function Successful!" );
                A();                   //CALL FUNCTION A
            },
        }); //End of AJAX
    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just a question: with the script like you put it function A will not run on init.. just only after Button1 is clicked or after 60 seconds. I added a A(); just before "$('#Button1').click(function() {". Is there another way of running the Script on page load?

Comment: After I click once on Button1, Function A it starts loading every 2-3 seconds instead of every 60s.. any ideas why?

Comment: @Emmanuel there is an additional } before complete remove that.

Comment: If I want to use the same Script of Button1 with Button 2, Button 3... Button N... do I need to copy the entire function "$('#ButtonX').click(function() {...}" N times?? Or is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To have the function running once while initiated and then use it again later you could create an **anonymous function** that returns itself like this:

```
var A = (function A() {
  // do the functions stuff
  return A;
})();
```

When you want to run it again it can be called using `A()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var A = (function A() {
    // stuff here
    return A;
  })();

  $('#Button1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "url",
      success: function(data){
        A();                   //CALL FUNCTION A
      }
    });
  })

});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, function A is loading at init --- yes.. BUT function A is running every 1 or 2 seconds instead of every 60 seconds.. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I've noticed that the delay changes only after I click once on Button1. That is,, no click on button1 everything work fines.. click on button1 --> Function A starts loading every 2-3 seconds instead of every 60s.. any ideas why?

Comment: Do you want it to run twice? using the button starts a second loop. if you don't want that second loop, you have to delete the timeout.

Comment: I need only 1 loop of function A.. it should start every 60 seconds OR with button 1 click... for example: Page load = First call.. after 25 seconds you click on button = second call.. that means the next call (if the button is not clicked) will be on second 85 (25+60) after page load..  I deleted "setTimeOut" and added a setInterval(A(), 60000); at the end of the script but it is not working..

Comment: Now i got it working.. Syntax error: correct use of "SetInterval" is:    setInterval(A, 60000);